# Material Design tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Google's [Material Design](http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html) style is a thing, and we're getting a slowly rising number of questions relating to it.

It's something people can be experts it, and something people can want to ignore. Sounds like what tags are for.

Should it have a tag?

Likewise for other real, defined styles, trends and publicly available design guidelines people ask about - should they have tags?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Any new tag is an innocent tag until proven guilty!

I agree we should have one for `Material Design`, because of its relevance but also because as it happens with all of them if it doesn't get used in two months it will get automatically deleted.

I suggest we afterwards go hunting for questions that deserve this new tag, but try to re-tag them in groups so we don't overflow the home with edits.

Answer (score 4):

I think we could have a tag for Material Design and Polymer. Especially since I just updated my phone to Lollipop over the weekend and it's full of their Material Design specifications (and beautiful I might add).

Might even look into it a fair bit on my own.

I'm more concerned that we have a [google](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google) which I wasn't aware of until today. No clue why we have that and think we might want to delete it. It's current Tag Wiki is:

> Google Inc. is an American multinational corporation specializing in Internet-related services and products. These include search, cloud computing, software, and online advertising technologies. Most of its profits are derived from AdWords.

Which has nothing to do with Graphic Design.

Comment: Google is a weird tag, but he questions tagged with it kind of make sense. The wiki is quite horrid, though.

Answer (score 4):

The tag exists now, but can I suggest renaming it to [google-material-design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-material-design),  as it's specific to that vendor's UI environment, and shouldn't be confused with wider subjects such as [print-design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/print-design), [website-design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/website-design), [information-design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/information-design), etc?

I think changing it requires fairly high rep score.

Comment: Sounds sensible to me

Comment: @e100 If you may, will you please create a new Q&A so we can address it later when some other mod or I have the time to work on it.

Comment: Great suggestion. I've performed the merge (with no synonym in case anyone wants to use [tag:material-design] for actual material design).

Comment: Thanks, @JohnB!